# Azure Devops Dashboard permissions

Tags: azure-devops

I have few teams part of same project collection who have different access requirement to the dashboard created in the project. Each team dashboard needs to be visible only to that team and not accessible by other teams. When I check the security on the Dashboards there is only **view and delete** access that can be either allowed or denied. Is it possible to achieve the different access at team level?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/dashboard-permissions?view=azure-devops):  all members of the Project Valid Users group can view dashboards.
There is no setting to limit visibility of the dashboard between teams.